# How can I traverse properties of an object in react

Tags: reactjs, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have created a generic datatable which receives an object (clients, products, travels, etc). I have a TravelsModel object that has a property mexican_currency_value. This value is defined with mongoose as:

```
var travelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: String,
        description: String,
        mexican_currency_value: mongoose.Schema.Types.Decimal128
    });
```

Also I have a function that returns a list with all the stored travels:

```
function getTravels(req, res) {

    if (req.params.id) {
        TravelModel.findById( String(req.params.id) , (err, value) => {
            if ( err ) {
                return res.status(500).send({
                    message: messageError
                })
            }
            return res.status(200).send({
                results: value
            });
        });
    } else {
        TravelModel.find((err, value) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).send({
                    message: messageError
                })
            }
            return res.status(200).send({
                results: value
            });
        });
    }
}
```

This function returns several travels with this structure:

```
  description: "Primer Viaje"
  mexican_currency_value: {$numberDecimal: "18.5"}
  name: "Viaje 1"
  __v: 0
  _id: "5cf56b04462a865264fabb9d"
```

My datatable is done more or less like this:

```
            <DataTable plain>
                <TableHeader>
                    <TableRow>
                        {tableColumnHeader.map(element => (
                            <TableColumn key={element.id}>{element.text}</TableColumn>
                        ))}
                        <TableColumn key="actions">Acciones</TableColumn>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableHeader>
                <TableBody>
                    {tableRow.map((element, idx) => (
                        <TableRow key={idx}>
                            <TableColumn>{tableColumnHeader.map( columns => ( 
                                <div key={element[columns.id]}>{element[columns.id]}</div>
                            ))}</TableColumn>
                            <ActionsMenu id={element._id} onDelete={onDelete} onUpdate={onUpdate} />
                        </TableRow>
                    ))}
                </TableBody>
                <TableFooter />
            </DataTable>
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$numberDecimal}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

This is because the travel object can not access element [columns.id], I would have to do element['mexican_currency_value']['$NumberDecimal']

**Is there any way to do something like element[columns.id].value? Or modify the way to return the data in mongoose?**

Answer (score 0):

> I'm getting this error:
>   The reason for that error is that you try to render an object, instead of rendering string or React component.
>
> Is there any way to do something like element[columns.id].value

Yes you can simply check

```js
typeof (element[columns.id]) === 'object' ? ((element[columns.id])).values().map(v => v) : (element[columns.id])
```

But I don't think that this is a good idea.

> Or modify the way to return the data in mongoose?

I think that the best approach will be to result in with numbers always for that key for the sake of the simplicity.